# How to prevent `-` and `+` charactor from input type number?

Tags: html, css

```html
<input type="number" min="0" step="1"  pattern="[0-9]" />

<br><br>
```

But the above input allows the `+` and `-` keys.  how to make this input type strictly allow only `0-9` without using `js`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Short and Simple trick

```html
<input type="number" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48" min="1" >
```

Comment: Technically speaking, you're using JS

Comment: @Louis yup buddy. It's using JS. Because it can't be done without JS.

Comment: @Louis is it 43 instead of 48?, because 48 still allows `+` character

Comment: @user2024080 if you want to allow + and - char then you should use 43. otherwise use 48 only for 0 to 9 char

Answer (score 0):

Not possible without JS.

```js
const allNumberInputs = document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type=number]' );
function disallowPrefixEvent( e ) {
  const keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if ( keyCode === 187 || keyCode === 189 ) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
for ( let i = 0; i < allNumberInputs.length; i += 1 ) {
  allNumberInputs[ i ].addEventListener( 'keydown', disallowPrefixEvent );
}
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" step="1"  pattern="[0-9]" />
```